# How can php read this parameter

Tags: php

If I have a stored input string that looks like this

```
http://site.com/param1/value1
```

how can php extract `value1`?

---

I know how to extract parameters that look like this

```
http://site.com?param1=value1
```

but it doesn't work for the format I'm asking about.

Comment: what do you exacly mean? because in this way you can use the $_GET?
Like `$_GET['param1']` his value is `value1`

Answer (score 2):

Generally you could parse url with parse_url and then explode path by / , and than read second value in array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple string function combination:

```
$str = "http://site.com/param1/value1";
$tail = substr($str, strrpos($str, "/") + 1);
```

Or if it's not sure if there is a `/` somewhere in the string:

```
preg_match("#/(\w+)$#", $string, $match);
$tail = $match[1];
```

For the microoptimizers: this too will generally be faster as the array-explode() workaround.

Comment: I will do this, as you're not always sure of the number of slashes (/) in your string. It can happen that the string deepens with one more directory, then all the above answers (not this one) WILL break, I guarantee you.

Answer (score 1):

Fast & Easy:

```
$url = "http://site.com/param1/value1";

$split_url = explode("/", $url);
$value = $split_url[3];
```

Comment: Assuming it's his site, get the URL from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Its index 4, not 3 (`$split_url[4]`).

Comment: @kingCrunch, fair enough
@Dan Grossman, doenst really matter just show him what possible way there is to get that `value1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/param1/value1';
list($param1, $value1) = array_slice(explode('/', $url), -2, 2);
```

This will give you param1 and value1 from the example stored in the variables $param1 and $value1.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some php.net manuals you can easily find this function, that totaly fits your needs

[strchr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

Comment: While you *could* use that to find a solution, that function only provides half the story, and its not as good an approach as just splitting the value.

Comment: I dont think so, there is everything on this manual page that you need. In the examples it sais "get everything after last newline", which can easily be transformet to "after last /"

Answer (score 0):

Look up parse_URL that's the function you want

Comment: Look it up and find out! Google "php parse_URL "

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a combination of Trickers and Toby Allens solution

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));
$value = $segments[2];
```

If you have multiple key-value-paris you can ensure with `trim()`, that the key is always even and the value always odd

```
$count = count($segments);
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
  $result[$segments[$i]] = $segments[$i+1];
}
```